# Events in the another html page doesn't working in Jquery mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have two html pages called page1.html and page2.html. In the first page i have a button which will load the second page, second page events doesn't work. My code is as follows

page1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
        <title>ShareQ</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


 <div data-role="page" class="container" id="pageTwo">

                <div data-role="header" class="mainHeader" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <span class="headerText">Scan QR</span>

                </div>

                <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="a" align="center">
                  <div data-role="info" class="textContainer">
                 De QR code wordt herkend! <br>
                    <span class="subTexts">Er zijn al aangemeld <span style="color: #C7DA2B;">3</span> ShareQ <br>
                        gebruikers 
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <a data-role="button" class="signUpbtn" align="center" id="signUpbtn" style="width:80%;" href="#pageWait" data-transition="slide">
                                    <span class="btnTxt">Meld je aan voor Queue</span>
                                    <img class="arrowClass" src="img/arrow.png" alt="" />
                    </a>

                  <a data-role="button" class="signUpbtn" align="center" id="msgBtn" style="width:80%;" href="chat.html" data-transition="slide">
                                    <span class="btnTxt">Verstuur bericht</span>
                                    <img class="arrowClass" src="img/arrow.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                  <div>
                    <img alt="logo" class="bgLogo" src="img/logobg.png">
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div data-role="footer" class="mainFooter" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="b">
                    <div data-role="navbar">
                        <ul class="navIcons">

                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-iconpos="top" class="icon-homeactive ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="homeactive" id="homeactivetwo">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-iconpos="top" class="icon-setngIcn ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="setngIcn" id="settingpgbtntwo">Instelligen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="top" class="icon-chatIcn ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="chatIcn" id="chatpgbtntwo">Berichten</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-iconpos="top" class="icon-infoIcn ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="infoIcn" id="infopgBtntwo">Informatie</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /navbar -->
                </div>
            </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chat.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mobileinit.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

`page2.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    </head>
    <body>

<div data-role="page" class="container" id="chatPage">

    <div data-role="header" class="mainHeader" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <span class="headerText">Send message</span>

    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="a" align="center">

        <div class="textContainer">
            <span class="subTexts">Select a standard text</span>
            <input id="preTextmsg" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="textContainer">

            <span class="subTexts">Set personal message together</span>
            <input id="enterText" type="text">
        </div>
        <a data-role="button" class="sendBtn" align="center" id="sendBtn">
            <span class="btnTxt">Send message</span>    
        </a>
        <div>
             <img alt="logo" class="bgLogo" src="img/logobg.png">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" class="mainFooter" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul class="navIcons">
                <li><a href="#" data-iconpos="top" class="icon-homeIcn ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="homeIcn" id="homepgbtn">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-iconpos="top" class="icon-setngIcn ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="setngIcn" id="settingpgbtn">Instelligen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-iconpos="top" class="icon-chatactive ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="chatactive" id="chatpgbtn">Berichten</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-iconpos="top" class="icon-infoIcn ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="infoIcn" id="regpgBtn">Informatie</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div>
</div>

      <!--      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chat.js"></script> -->

 </body>
</html>
```

and the page1.html js code is,

```
$(document).on('pagecreate',function( event, ui ){
//$( "#homePage" ).on( "pagecreate", function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).unbind('pagecreate');
    hmPageLoad();

});

function hmPageLoad(){
    $("#homePage").on( "pagebeforeshow", function(evt){

    });
    $("#homePage").on( "pageshow",function(evt){
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onReady, false);
        function onReady(){
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false );

            app.checkPlatform();
            app.checkConnection();

            $('#homepgbtn').on( "tap", function(evt){

                $.mobile.changePage('#homePage',{ transition: "slide"});

            });
            $('#settingpgbtn').on( "tap", function(evt){


            });
            $('#chatpgbtn').on( "tap", function(evt){


            });
            $('#infopgBtn').on( "tap", function(evt){

            });
}
});
}
```

and page2.html js is,

```
$("#chatPage").on( "pagebeforeshow", function(evt){

});
$("#chatPage").on( "pageshow",function(evt){
    $(this).unbind('pageshow');
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){


    app.checkConnection();
    alert('test chat page');
    $('#chhomepgbtn').on( "tap", function(evt){

        $.mobile.changePage('index.html#homePage',{ transition: "slide"});

    });
    $('#chsettingpgbtn').on( "tap", function(evt){

        $.mobile.changePage('index.html#settngPage',{ transition: "slide"});    

    });
    $('#chchatpgbtn').on( "tap", function(evt){


        $.mobile.changePage('#chatPage',{ transition: "slide"});
    });
    $('#chregpgBtn').on( "tap", function(evt){
        alert('test info');


    });
   }, false);

});
```

When i press the link button which has id = "msgBtn" it loads the page2.html. But now if i pressed any of the link buttons in page2.html, its not working. Not even the alert messages.
I dont know whether i have followed the right method or not since i am new to phonegap and jquery mobile. Please guide me in the right path.

Thanks & regards,
Anand Tagore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For us to understand this situation we need to understand how jQuery Mobile works. It uses **AJAX** for page loading into the **DOM**.

First page is loaded normally. Its **HEAD** and **BODY** is loaded into the DOM. That content will stay there (unless page is refreshed) to await further content loading. When second page is loaded, only its **BODY** content is loaded into the **DOM**, and when I say its BODY content I mean **DIV** with an attribute **data-role=”page”** and its inner content.

This may not sound as something problematic but you should think twice. What if we have several **HTML** pages and every and each page has something unique, lets say different JavaScript intended to be used only during that page execution, not to mention additional CSS files. Everything found in a **HEAD** of those files are going to be discarded and its JavaScript  is not going to be executed.

Unfortunately you are not going to find this described in their documentation. This is ether thought to be a common knowledge or it is just forgotten to be describe.

There are several solutions to this problem, some are good and some are bad, everything should depend on a project architecture.

Solution to this problem can be found **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**.

Comment: Yes,I'l inform you :)

Comment: I've included my js file in the datarole="page",and now it works fine. Thanks a lot for yous help